# Need to remove duplication content on home page in wordpress theme

Tags: posts

I am trying to develop a simple site on wordpress. I have been trying to remove the duplicating content from home page for hours now, but I am unable to find how to remove that entire row that I pointed in this image

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Simply not enough information here to form an answer.  What you appear to want to remove is a standard post, titled "Home".  Is the rest of the page a WP "page" with static content or is a page full of posts?  Is the "home" post repeated?  Your screenshot does not show any duplication

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment yet, so I am going to try and answer your question with the small amount of info you have provided.

The area you show in the red box seems to be a post and not a page. You should make sure that your home page content is on an actual page and then delete the post.

Next double check you have set your page as the home page in the dash: **Settings > Reading**. Here you can select "**Static Page**" then choose which page to use as your home page from a drop down list.

If this doesn't solve the problem we'll need to see your theme code to help more.